# How do you mock an UpdateOneAsync method returning bool using NSubstitute and XUnit?

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit, nsubstitute

This is the method I need to test and it will always return false

```
private async Task<bool> UpdateUsername(string newName, User user)
        {

                var update = Builders<User>.Update.Set(entity => entity.Name, newName);

                await repository.UpdateOneAsync(entity => entity.Id == user.Id, update);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Would doing sth like this suffice

```
repository.UpdateOneAsync(Arg.Any<User>(), updateTerms).Returns(false);
```

And what should I pass into the updateTerms?

Comment: You can refer to the examples in this article, which may be helpful to you: https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/getting-started/

Comment: can you tell the output type of Builders<User>.Update.Set method?